# How optaplanner constraint will sort the jobs base on priority and pick the job who's priority is high(1 means priority is high)

Tags: optaplanner

Job is planning entity class and Project is PlanningSolution class contains list of Jobs.
Our expectations are:-
1.We have 3 jobs that need to be sorted according to priority(ascending order).
2. After sorting, startdate of first job should be next day of readyDate i.e (2023-02-02 +1=2023-02-03). and second job's start date will be the next day of first job's endDate.
StartDate Calculation will be :- only for first job startDate will be next day of readyDate and for next jobs startDate will be next day of previous job's endDate
End Date calculation : startDate + Duration

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Job {
private String jobName;
private int duration;
// startDate should be change 
@PlanningVariable
private LocalDate startDate;
// endDate should be change
@PlanningVariable
private LocalDate endDate;
private LocalDate readyDate;
private int priority;
}

@PlanningSolution
public class Project
{
List<Job> jobs;
@PlanningScore
private HardSoftLongScore hardSoftLongScore;
}
```

```
Below is input to optaplanner:-
{
    "Job": [
        {
            "jobName": "P3",
        "duration":4,
            "startDate": "2023-02-05",
            "endDate": "2023-02-07",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 3
        },
        {
            "jobName": "P2",
            "duration":2,
            "startDate": "2023-02-01",
            "endDate": "2023-02-07",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 1
        },
        {
            "jobName": "P1",
        "duration":3,
            "startDate": "2023-02-06",
            "endDate": "2023-02-07",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Expected Result :
{
    "Job": [        
        {
            "jobName": "P2",
            "duration":2,
            "startDate": "2023-02-03",
            "endDate": "2023-02-04",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 1
        },
        {
            "jobName": "P1",
         "duration":3,
            "startDate": "2023-02-05",
            "endDate": "2023-02-07",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "jobName": "P3",
        "duration":4,
            "startDate": "2023-02-08",
            "endDate": "2023-02-11",
            "readyDate": "2023-02-02",
            "priority": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Tried with below code to sort jobs but its not working as expected

private Constraint startDate(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Job.class)
        .filter((j1,j2)->j1.getPriority().compareTo(j2.getPriority()))
        .penalize(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD)
        .asConstraint("Sort jobs according to priority");
}
```

Can anyone from optaplanner knowledge help here?

Comment: is optaplanner result is inconsistent frequently for same dataset?